# Python 2.7 accepting capital letters

Tags: python

So i've got this program and it basically encrypts text in many different ways (for exam practise) and i don't know how to make the menu function accept capital letters aswell as lower case letters

```
def GetMenuChoice():
  MenuChoice = raw_input()
  print
  return MenuChoice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `str.lower()` or `str.upper()` to convert your text to all lowercase or all uppercase:

```
def GetMenuChoice():
  MenuChoice = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
  return MenuChoice.lower()

expected="Menu1"
while GetMenuChoice() != expected.lower():
    print "Try again"
print "Correct input"
```

demo:

```
Enter your choice: menu
Try again
Enter your choice: mennu
Try again
Enter your choice: mEnU1
Correct input
```

Comment: Thanks, i've got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write terminal apps, i strongly recommend using [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html). But as a quick hack, simply transform it to either lower or upper case and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> MenuChoice = raw_input()
A
>>> MenuChoice = MenuChoice.lower()
>>> MenuChoice
'a'
```

This was you can always deal with one case, by calling `.lower` or `.upper` on the users input.